# Spring data jpa: join on column with a prefix in the data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables that I want to join, but the value to join on isn't the same in both tables. Is there a way to do this with annotations instead of writing the JPQL or SQL myself? I've looked at the properties in `@JoinColumn` but none of them seem related to my problem.

I want to join `on table_one.fk = 'prefix_' || table_two.fk`

Table one:

```
id    fk
--------
1     fk1
2     fk2
3     fk3
4     fk4
```

Table two:

```
id        fk
--------------------
uuid1     prefix_fk1
uuid2     prefix_fk2
uuid3     prefix_fk3
uuid4     prefix_fk4
```

Comment: If Hibernate then maybe `@JoinFormula`. Otherwise database view with normalized column(s) mapped to your entity via `@SecondaryTable` might be a possibility. Additional notes: join on non PK columns is not required to be supported (from memory, I think Hibernate does however).